# Path of a php array

Tags: php, prestashop

I would like to remove in the result of my table all users belonging to a group in particular, knowing that it can belong to several groups. How could I do that?

I'd start by making a query is a foreach loop this way

```
$arrayCustomer = [];

    $customers = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('
                SELECT c.id_customer, c.email, c.firstname, c.lastname, cg.id_group
                FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'customer c
                LEFT JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'customer_group cg ON(c.id_customer = cg.id_customer)
                WHERE c.active = 1 ');

    foreach ($customers as $key => $customer) {
        $arrayCustomer[$key] = $customer;
    }
```

[image]

Thank you for help.

Comment: sample input and output?

Comment: yes sorry I forgot

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `GROUP BY`  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: GROUP BY cg.id_group ? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove them directly from the query, you can add a subselect:

```
SELECT c.id_customer, c.email, c.firstname, c.lastname, cg.id_group
FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'customer c
LEFT JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'customer_group cg ON(c.id_customer = cg.id_customer)
WHERE c.active = 1
    AND cg.id_customer NOT IN (SELECT cg.id_customer FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'customer_group cg WHERE cg.id_group = GROUP_ID)
```

*Replace GROUP_ID with the desired group*

Comment: Ok its ok with this. Thank you for help guys.